# Can I have Pikachu/Eevee follow me again?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

At the beginning of the game Pikachu was following me around, can I have them back out behind me like this once more?

I noticed that I can let other pokemon out of the ball, but it seems like Pikachu is just staying on my shoulder.

Comment: Can you not have Pikachu/Eevee in your party and set as your follow Pokemon? I'm pretty sure you can do it with any Pokemon you own (which includes your initial Eevee/Pikachu)

Comment: I don't have the option, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your partner Eevee/Pikachu cannot follow you after a certain point of the story.
They will be on your head/shoulder instead.
In addition, your partner Eevee/Pikachu cannot evolve.

What you can do is get another Eevee/Pikachu. They will follow you and are able to evolve.

Comment: It's really sad :(

Comment: At least the partner has full 6 IV :)